# using directive -- why so strange behaviour?

Tags: c++

I have this sample code

```
namespace ns1
{
    void foo(int)
    {
    }
}

namespace ns2
{
    void foo()
    {
    }
    void bar()
    {
        using namespace ::ns1;
        foo(42); // why compiler can't just call ns1::foo?
    }
}
```

And it doesn't compile with error:

```
prog.cpp:16:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘void ns2::foo()’
```

I found reason of this error in C++ 2003 standard:

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace
>   can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after
>   the using-directive. During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), **the names
>   appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace
>   which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace.**
>   [Note: in this context, “contains” means “contains directly or
>   indirectly”. ]

Is any **rationale** for this strange rule? Why names from namespace ns1 can't directly appear in namespace ns2?

Comment: Since I've never seen 'using' used this way, I'll venture a guess.  It tries to pull the name into the current namespace, and probably not as you intend to pull into the function context only.  The collision of the two functions then probably is a problem.

Comment: You give the compiler a choice, both ns1::foo and ns2::foo are in scope.  Which one do you think it should pick?  The closest or the furthest?  Do you like it when the compiler picks a global variable with the same name as a function parameter?  And if you say "ns1::foo of course!" then why not just write it that way?

Comment: According to D&E, using-directives "renders names accessible". Since we (potentially) don't know the full set of names made accessible, it's more conservative and puts them further up in the namespace hierarchy (so they don't accidentally hide names). The nearest enclosing namespace might be interpreted as common part of the program; anything enclosing is less specialized, anything enclosed is more specialized and should therefore take priority. But I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this was/is done in an attempt at reducing conflicts and surprises. Names brought into scope by a `using` directive are visible, but anything that's directly contained in the local scope will take precedence over it.

If you really want to call you function without a qualified ID, you make it visible with a `using` declaration instead:

```
namespace ns1 {
    void foo(int) { }
}

namespace ns2 {
    void foo() { }
    void bar() {
        using ::ns1::foo;
        foo(42); // No problem; calls ::ns1::foo.
    }
}
```

Comment: I know of possibility using using declaration, but the question exactly about using directive.

Comment: @maxim.yurchuk: Yes--that's why I answered the question about the `using` directive first, and only once I'd done that added information about one possible workaround.

Comment: about reducing conflicts and surprises: I think this example: https://ideone.com/qdGaCC is rather surprising.

Answer (score 2):

`ns1::foo` is being hidden by the declaration of `ns2::foo`

From N3337, *§3.3.10/1* **[basic.scope.hiding]**

> A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region or derived class (10.2).

The section you've quoted (*§7.3.4/2*) is immediately followed by

> *3*   A *using-directive* does not add any members to the declarative region in which it appears. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
>     namespace A {
>       int i;
>       namespace B {
>         namespace C {
>           int i;
>         }
>         using namespace A::B::C;
>         void f1() {
>           i = 5; // OK, C::i visible in B and hides A::i
>         }
>       }
>       // more (irrelevant) stuff
>     }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

In your case, the *using-directive* is introducing the names in `ns1` to the common ancestor namespace of where it appears, and that of `ns1`, meaning the global namespace. It **does not** introduce them within `ns2`, so the declaration of `ns2::foo` hides that of `ns1::foo`.

If you want `ns1::foo` to be found, use a using declaration instead.

```
void bar()
{
    using ::ns1::foo;
    foo(42);
}
```

Comment: I know this facts and I understand why this code doesn't compile. I asked about explanation of this rules: why using declaration introduce names in scope, but using directive doesn't?

Comment: @maxim.yurchuk This is an *explanation* of the rules. If you're looking the *rationale* of why they work this way, then JerryCoffin's answer might be the one you're looking for. I am not aware of any other reason.